# JQuery Tooltip Problem

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I've a webpage [You can see webpage here!](http://doonella.com/demo/demo.html). There is a facebook user image. When I hover mouse over this then it show tooltip but when I leave mouse from this then it reload the image. To see this reloading image on mouse leave, you can see status bar of your browser. I don't want to reload this image. Please see the source code and help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I agree...looks totally fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah looks like its working just fine.

You should use Firebug for debugging stuff like this. Use the "Net" tab and you will be able to see that the image is not actually reloading.

http://getfirebug.com/

Another (not free) great way of testing is Charles for Mac OSX. Its really good.